# How to check if values exists in table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a bit trouble finding the right solution for what I'm trying to do.
I have a table:

```js
var _1 = "Something1";
var _2 = "Something2";
var result = "dsadas";
$('<tr><td>' + _1 + '</td><td>' + _2 + '</td><td>' + result + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#test');
```

```css
td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gr">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Something1</th>
      <th>Something2</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="test">
    <tr>
      <td>Something1</td>
      <td>Something2</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm pushing it like I showed u above.

And when I'm adding new  element dynamically I want to check if values of  columns im pushing into table exist in the table and:
If not, push new one, if exist, just change the result column.
How can I archive that?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Just did the dynamically adding thing, and I don't have an idea for the rest. So, I don't really have any attempted code for the checking in the table. :/

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: @Hatchling The simplest way is `if($('table tr td').text() == '32')`

Comment: @Mr.x The problem is that I don't want to check the column based on Result, but on the first and second column which is Something 1 and Something 2 in my case. And if these 2 values match to these values I want to push, then change the result.

Comment: how u add tr dynamically to the table?

Comment: @Hatchling All depends how you append dynamically. Update your post with code, it helps to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mr.x Updated my post.

Comment: so which value should be matched something1 or something2 or both the values should be checked while appending?

Comment: @Hatchling A little bit unclear what you asking. I read your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786571/how-to-check-if-values-exists-in-table-row#comment82534327_47786571) many times but not understand what you want.. the answer below not solved your problem?

Comment: Let's Say My column looks like that: Test1 | Test 2 | Result I'm pushing dynamically Test1 | Test2 | Result, now as you can see, I'm pushing same values, which I already have in the table, in this case I only want to update my result by 1 let's say. Else, if these values doesn't match, add the whole column normally

Comment: @Hatchling See [This](https://jsfiddle.net/56m4yLfj/), not sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $("#addtr").on('submit', function(){
        var something1 = $("#something1").val();
        var something2 = $("#something2").val();
        var result = $("#result").val();
        var inc = 0;
            
        var cnt = 0;    
        $('#tbody tr').each(function(i, el){
            var value1 = $(el).children().eq(0).text();
            var value2 = $(el).children().eq(1).text();
            var res = $(el).children().eq(2).text();
            if(value1 == something1 && value2 == something2){
                inc = (inc)+1;
                res = parseInt(res)+(1);
                $(this).children(":eq(2)").text(res);
            }
            cnt = cnt+1;
        })
        if(inc == 0){
            var add = "<tr><td>"+something1+"</td><td>"+something2+"</td><td>"+result+"</td></tr>";
                $(".gr tbody").append(add);
        } else {
            //console.log("exist");
        }
         
        return false;
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table class="gr">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Something1</th>
      <th>Something2</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tbody'>
    <tr>
      <td>Something1</td>
      <td>Something2</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form method='post' action='#' id='addtr'>
    <input type='text' name='something1' id='something1' />
    <input type='text' name='something2' id='something2' />
    <input type='text' name='result' id='result' />
    <button type='submit' id='submit'>Add</button>
</form>
```

I think this could be solution to your problem please check i am adding dynamic input using textbox please enter the same value in the both textbox then the result value will be incremented otherwise new `<tr>` will be created

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help to achieve what you need:

```js
var _1 = "Something1";
var _2 = "Something2";
var result = "dsadas";

var change = false;
$("tbody#test").find("tr").each(function() {
  var $td = jQuery(this).find("td");
  if ($td.first()[0].innerHTML == _1 && $td.next()[0].innerHTML == _2) {
    change = true;
    $td.last()[0].innerHTML = result;
  }

});

if (!change) {
  $('<tr><td>' + _1 + '</td><td>' + _2 + '</td><td>' + result + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#test');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="gr">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Something1</th>
      <th>Something2</th>
      <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="test">
    <tr>
      <td>Something1</td>
      <td>Something2</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```